# How to jump back to second previous page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a `drawer` in Flutter. And a `refer and earn section` in it. Now, whenever I click on that, I will be redirected to refer page. And when I will press back button on `appbar`, I come back to the drawer widget. This is working fine and accordingly. Now, I want that whenever I click on back button from refer page, my `drawer` should be closed and I reach to the main screen. How should i do it?

Answer (score 2):

It's referred to go back to the first page where you start. Whether this route is the bottom-most active route on the navigator.
If isFirst and isCurrent are both true then this is the only route on the navigator (and isActive will also be true).

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below method to navigate back-

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Pretty simple, when I tap, pop the drawer using `Navigator.pop(context)` and then Navigate to the next page. So, when I clicked back arrow, I got to the main/previous screen.